Convert audio to MP3: 4 frames left in the queue on closing
I am trying to convert AMR audio to MP3:
        ByteArrayInputStream amrStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(amrData);
        ByteArrayOutputStream mp3Stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(amrStream);
             FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(mp3Stream, grabber.getAudioChannels())) {
            
            grabber.setFormat("amr");
            grabber.start();

            recorder.setFormat("mp3");
            int sampleRate = grabber.getSampleRate();

            recorder.setSampleRate( sampleRate < MIN_SAMPLE_RATE ? MIN_SAMPLE_RATE : sampleRate);
            recorder.setAudioChannels(grabber.getAudioChannels());

            // The AMR low bitrate sounds better then same bitrate on mp3, so we increase it
            int bitrate = grabber.getAudioBitrate();
            recorder.setAudioBitrate(bitrate < MIN_BITRATE ? MIN_BITRATE : bitrate);
            recorder.start();

            Frame frame;
            while ((frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
                if (frame.samples != null) {
                    recorder.record(frame);
                }
            }
            recorder.flush();
            recorder.release();
            grabber.release();
            recorder.stop();
            grabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to convert AMR to MP3", e);
        }

For some reason, the output mp3 file is always cut for half of a second.
And in logs, I can see:
[libmp3lame @ 000002106e0b26c0] 4 frames left in the queue on closing
Any ideas on how I can flush those 4 frames to my output steam?
I tried flushing with Thread.sleep(), other order of release/stop calls, nothing works.
